How to draw a rounded filled rectangle with only the corners anti aliased using GDI+?
I'm trying to draw a rounded rectangle with anti-aliased corners, however the entire rectangle is being aliased, resulting in blured edges of the rectangle. I'd like to only have the rounded corners anti-aliased, keeping the sides of the rectangle well defined.

The code below produces the Line Only and Fill Only output, but how can I get something that looks closer to the Expected image on the far right? (manually created in MS Paint)
void GetRoundRectPath2(GraphicsPath* pPath, Rect r, int dia)
{
    // diameter can't exceed width or height
    if (dia > r.Width)    dia = r.Width;
    if (dia > r.Height)    dia = r.Height;

    // define a corner 
    Rect Corner(r.X, r.Y, dia, dia);

    // begin path
    pPath->Reset();

    // top left
    pPath->AddArc(Corner, 180, 90);

    // tweak needed for radius of 10 (dia of 20)
    if (dia == 20)
    {
        Corner.Width += 1;
        Corner.Height += 1;
        r.Width -= 1; r.Height -= 1;
    }

    // top right
    Corner.X += (r.Width - dia - 1);
    pPath->AddArc(Corner, 270, 90);

    // bottom right
    Corner.Y += (r.Height - dia - 1);
    pPath->AddArc(Corner, 0, 90);

    // bottom left
    Corner.X -= (r.Width - dia - 1);
    pPath->AddArc(Corner, 90, 90);

    // end path
    pPath->CloseFigure();
}

void FillRoundRect2(Graphics* pGraphics, Brush* pBrush, Rect r, Color border, int radius)
{
    int dia = 2 * radius;

    // set to pixel mode
    int oldPageUnit = pGraphics->SetPageUnit(UnitPixel);

    // define the pen
    Pen pen(border, 1);
    pen.SetAlignment(PenAlignmentCenter);

    // get the corner path
    GraphicsPath path;

    // get path
    GetRoundRectPath2(&path, r, dia);

    // fill
    pGraphics->FillPath(pBrush, &path);

    // draw the border last so it will be on top
    pGraphics->DrawPath(&pen, &path);

    // restore page unit
    pGraphics->SetPageUnit((Unit)oldPageUnit);
}

Graphics graphics(dc);
graphics.SetSmoothingMode(SmoothingModeAntiAlias);

// Line only
SolidBrush sbrA(Gdiplus::Color(0,255,0,0)); // Full Transparent
FillRoundRect2(&graphics, &sbrA, Gdiplus::Rect(10, 10, 40, 40), Gdiplus::Color(50, 255, 0, 0), 5);

// Fill only
SolidBrush sbr(Gdiplus::Color(50, 255, 0, 0));
FillRoundRect2(&graphics, &sbr, Gdiplus::Rect(10, 10, 40, 40), Gdiplus::Color(0, 255, 0, 0), 5);

Update:
I've fonud an approach that is working fairly well. First I create a region that is the exact size of the rounded rectangle I want to draw using SetClip. Then I offset the the corrdinates passed to FillRoundRect2, left and top by -1, and increased the width and height by 2. This means that the aliased edges now fall outside of the drawing region.
Region myRegion(Rect(10, 10, 40, 40));
graphics.SetClip(&myRegion, CombineModeReplace);

SolidBrush sbr(Gdiplus::Color(50, 255, 0, 0));
FillRoundRect2(&graphics, &sbr, Gdiplus::Rect(10-1, 10-1, 40+2, 40+2), Gdiplus::Color(0, 255, 0, 0), 7);



Sorry, it's been too long since I've done GDI+.  Does the SetSmoothingMode make a difference, as per Antialiasing with Lines and Curves?

Sorry yes I'm already using SetSmoothingMode(SmoothingModeAntiAlias); but that results in everything being smoothed.

How about if you Pen pen(border, 2);?  Or PenAlignmentInset rather than PenAlignmentCenter?

As I'm drawing the pen with 100% transparent pen those changes made no difference.

How about if you draw the pen with 0% transparent?

@Eljay, If I use 0% transparent, I get a filled rectangle with a border, but I don't wont a border, my brush has an alpha component of 50, as I'm ultimately drawing this shape over a backgroud, when I tried to use a pen and brush both with an alpha of 50, the line causes a border also.

@Eljay Please see an update in my question, as I've found that using a region and SetClip gives a good result. Just not sure if it's the correct approach. But it works.

The rounded corners are off by half-a-pixel for their AA.  But other than that, the rule is:  if it looks good, it's good.
